Using inclusion exclusion to find the number of ways to arrange a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c such that no adjacent letters are the same?
When trying to solve this problem I considered the principle of inclusion exclusion where the set U is the number of all possible arrangements, the set A is the number of arrangements that have "aa", the set B is the number of arrangements with "bb", and the set C is the number of arrangements with "cc." Then
$$N(U) = P(9;3,3,3),$$ $$N(A)=N(B)=N(C)=P(8;3,3,1),$$ $$N(A \cap B) = N(A \cap C) = N(B \cap C) = P(7;3,1,1),$$ $$ N(A \cap B \cap C) = 6!$$
Using $N(U)-N(A \cup B \cup C)$ and the inclusion exclusion principle I obtained the answer:
$$ \frac{9!}{3!3!3!} - 3 \frac{8!}{3!3!} + 3 \frac{7!}{3!} - 6!$$
as the number of arrangements without two adjacent letters the same.
However, does the fact that their is three of each letter impact my approach? Any advice would be appreciated!

Seems okay for me, but what do you mean by "There is three of each letter I could have "aa" in the sequence?

You should show more of your work. We can't see your answer, nor any of the calculations that lead to it!

See the link. Some answers there are exactly what you seek.
